# I want to create input as many as num_of_house. if num_of _house=5 than 5 inputes. How can I make it

Tags: python

```
cat = list(input("Coordinates of cat: "))
dog = list(input("Coordinates of dog: "))
num_of_house = int(input("Number of house: "))

for k in range(num_of_house):
    str(k) = list(input("Coordinates of house: "))
```

OUTPUT: SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call

Comment: you want to use a list or dictionary here

Comment: `str(k)` converts the value of `k` to a string. What are you trying to do by assigning to that?

Comment: What's `num_of_nor`?

Answer (score 0):

You want something like:

```
house_coords = [list(input("Coordinates of house: ")) for _ in range(num_of_house)]
```

This will give you a list of lists which has `num_of_house` elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
houses = [input("Coordinates of house: ") for _ in range(num_of_house)]
```